# php session variable in a different environment won't work

Tags: php, session, session-variables

The following script works under windows xampp, php 5.3.8

```
session_start();
    if (empty($_SESSION['myvar']) && empty($_GET['myvar'])) {
        $myvar = "some_value";
    } elseif (!empty($_GET['myvar'])) {
        $_SESSION['myvar'] = $_GET['myvar'];
    }
    $_SESSION['myvar'] = $myvar;
```

but on ubuntu server, php 5.3.10  if I `var_dump($myvar)` the value is `null`

Comment: Well, if `myvar` is already set in the session and not in the url parameters, what _should_ the value be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered you may be defining your session variable twice, overwriting the first defined within your if statement?  Also if you were to run the following code while !empty($_GET['myvar']) is true:

```
session_start();
if (empty($_SESSION['myvar']) && empty($_GET['myvar'])) {
    $myvar = "some_value";
} elseif (!empty($_GET['myvar'])) {
    $_SESSION['myvar'] = $_GET['myvar'];
}
$_SESSION['myvar'] = $myvar;
```

You would most likley get an undefined variable warning because your not setting $myvar.  Try this:

```
session_start();
if (empty($_SESSION['myvar']) && empty($_GET['myvar'])) {
    $myvar = "some_value";
    $_SESSION['myvar'] = $myvar;
} elseif (!empty($_GET['myvar'])) {
    $_SESSION['myvar'] = $_GET['myvar'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and the correction but I'm still not able to retrieve the value of $myvar as var_dump($myvar).

Answer (score 0):

You only add value to `$myvar` if the session or the get parameter is empty. Otherwise it is null.
How about this:

```
session_start();
$my_var = isset($_SESSION['my_var'] ? $_SESSION['my_var'] : 'default_value';
if(empty($_SESSION['myvar']) && empty($_GET['myvar'])){
    $myvar = 'some_value';
} elseif(!empty($_GET['my_var'))) {
    $myvar = $_GET['myvar'];
}
$_SESSION['my_var'] = $myvar;
```

Or simply:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['my_var'] = isset($_GET['my_var']) ? $_GET['my_var'] : (isset($_SESSION['my_var']) ? $_SESSION['my_var'] : 'default_value');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
empty($_SESSION['myvar']) && empty($_GET['myvar'])
```

It's false for all time.
Becase on fist time $_SESSION['myvar'] is empty, and $_GET['myvar'] not empty：

```
$_SESSION['myvar'] = $myvar; // now $myvar is empty



 if (empty($_SESSION['myvar']) && empty($_GET['myvar'])) {
        $_SESSION['myvar'] = "some_value";
    } elseif (!empty($_GET['myvar'])) {
        $_SESSION['myvar'] = $_GET['myvar'];
    }
```